# Visualizing Polyhedra

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, visualization

I'm currently taking an intro course in nanotechnology and was introduced to Euler's formula while reading ($V + F - E = 2$). The formula was introduced in the context of bucky balls (carbon based structures with 20 hexagonal faces and 12 pentagonal faces), but another example was given to prove why the pentagonal faces were necessary. The example reads as follows:

***"If one imagines starting to build [a closed shape using only hexagons] with the first three hexagons brought together along their edges, it is easy to see that each pair shares an edge ($E = F/2$) and that each triple shares two verticies ($V = 3F/2$) so that $V - E + F = 0$, proving that completing a closed shape without gaps is impossible unless one also uses tiles with a different shape."*** (*Introduction to Nanoscience and Nanotechnology*, Chris Binns, pg. $58$)

Now, I definitely have a lot to learn when it comes to geometry, but for whatever reason I've been having such a hard time visualizing what is meant here and understanding where the relations such as $E = F/2$ are coming from. Could someone possible explain it to me in a different way or provide a visual of some sort?

Comment: I think $E=F/2$ is simply wrong.

Comment: Put a pebble on each side of each edge. There are six pebbles in each (hexagonal) face, so the number of pebbles is $6F$, but also two pebbles associated to each edge, so the number of pebbles is $2E$. Thus, $6F=2E$, so $E=3F$. As @Chris writes, $E=F/2$ is nonsense.

Comment: Putting a pebble in each angle similarly yields $6F=3V$, so $V=2F$.

Comment: In the quoted paragraph, it says $E=F/2$ and $V=3F/2$, but in your own last paragraph you write you have a hard time understanding where $E=3F/2$ comes from. Evidently, it comes from you, since it's not in the paragraph you quote.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson, this makes so much sense now. I realize my issue what that I was focusing on the the phrase “...the first three hexagons brought together...,” when in reality it was better to think of each individual face. What you wrote clears things up.

Comment: Glad I could help, Jinx.